# data wrangling with Flask: how to do this using SQL language? Does it make sense to use pandas?

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, data-munging

Quite new to SQL, and working with flask and sqlalchemy here is my issue (I hope it's not too long)

### Overview:

I have a SQL table structured like this:

```
name    vector       axis       value       unit    ref 
----------------------------------------------------------------    
name1       v1          W       46504       psi     ref1
name1       v1          L       51757       psi     ref1
name1       v2          W         127       psi     another ref
name1       v2          L         403       psi     ref1
name2 ...
```

My aim is to "unstack" the results such as I could have one row per `name` as long as `unit` and `ref` are the same.

e.g. I wish to get something like:

```
name      v1-L      v2-W    v1-L    v2-W    unit    ref
--------------------------------------------------------------
name1    46504               127    403     psi    ref1
name1                127                    psi    another ref
name2...
```

### Trying with sqlalchemy:

so far, I tried to join the same table based on 'name' --for now, no check on `unit` neither `ref` --:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Table, Text, Date, Float
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import  sessionmaker, aliased
engine = create_engine('sqlite://') #, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    vector = Column(String(32))
    axis = Column(String(1))
    value = Column(Float)
    unit = Column(String(16), default='psi')
    ref = Column(String(32))

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# some data to play with
data = [{'name':'name1', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'W', 'value':'46504', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name1', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'L', 'value':'51757', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name1', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'W', 'value':'127', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'another ref'},
        {'name':'name1', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'L', 'value':'403', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'L', 'value':'23000', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'W', 'value':'27000', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'L', 'value':'523', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'W', 'value':'217', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},]
for dic in data:
    t = Test(**dic)
    session.add(t)
session.commit()

test_alias = aliased(Test)
q = session.query(Test.id, Test.name, Test.value).filter(Test.vector == 'v1').\
    join(test_alias, Test.name).filter(test_alias.vector == 'v2')
print q
```

### Example using pandas:

Here is what I would get using `pandas` library.

```
import pandas as pd
q = session.query(Test).order_by(Test.id) # that is the default table
row2dict = lambda r: {c.name: getattr(r, c.name) for c in r.__table__.columns}
df = pd.DataFrame([row2dict(i) for i in q])
df = df.drop(['id'], axis=1)

df = df.set_index(['ref', 'unit', 'name', 'vector', 'axis']).sort()
df = df.unstack(level=-2).unstack(level=-1)['value'].reset_index()
print(df)

vector          ref unit   name     v1          v2     
axis                                 L      W    L    W
0       another ref  psi  name1    NaN    NaN  NaN  127
1              ref1  psi  name1  51757  46504  403  NaN
2              ref1  psi  name2  23000  27000  523  217
```

...which is not so far from my expect.

So does it make sense to do this in SQL language? Thus my following question is: using `Flask` framework, does it make sense to do this data munging using pandas? or should I stick to SQL-language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas is probably better for this kind of thing.  There might be some more exotic SQL functions that do a transformation like this, but I'm not sure.  Below is your example doing the most simplistic approach, which is just to JOIN a view of each one together.  The way this comes to mind is that since you are producing rows that have "virtual" columns derived from data, that suggests a composite row is being created from more fundamental rows.  So the approach below breaks out a set of rows corresponding to each of the four conditions, v1/W, v1/L, v2/W, v2/L.   Now if in practice, there's any number of "vN", that's where the transformational ability of Pandas is probably more appropriate.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, aliased

Base = declarative_base()

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32))
    vector = Column(String(32))
    axis = Column(String(1))
    value = Column(Float)
    unit = Column(String(16), default='psi')
    ref = Column(String(32))

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
session = Session(engine)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

# some data to play with
data = [{'name':'name1', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'W', 'value':'46504', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name1', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'L', 'value':'51757', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name1', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'W', 'value':'127', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'another ref'},
        {'name':'name1', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'L', 'value':'403', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'L', 'value':'23000', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v1', 'axis':'W', 'value':'27000', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'L', 'value':'523', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},
        {'name':'name2', 'vector':'v2', 'axis':'W', 'value':'217', 'unit':'psi', 'ref':'ref1'},]
for dic in data:
    t = Test(**dic)
    session.add(t)
session.commit()

axis_w = session.query(Test).filter(Test.axis == "W")
axis_l = session.query(Test).filter(Test.axis == "L")
axis_v1_w = axis_w.filter(Test.vector == "v1").subquery()
axis_v1_l = axis_l.filter(Test.vector == "v1").subquery()
axis_v2_w = axis_w.filter(Test.vector == "v2").subquery()
axis_v2_l = axis_l.filter(Test.vector == "v2").subquery()

def join_axes(left, right):
    return and_(
                left.c.unit == right.c.unit,
                left.c.ref == right.c.ref
            )

name_unit_ref = session.query(Test.name, Test.unit, Test.ref).distinct().subquery()

q = session.query(name_unit_ref.c.name,
                axis_v1_w.c.value.label('v1_w'),
                axis_v1_l.c.value.label('v1_l'),
                axis_v2_w.c.value.label('v2_w'),
                axis_v2_l.c.value.label('v2_l'),
                name_unit_ref.c.unit,
                name_unit_ref.c.ref
            ).\
            outerjoin(axis_v1_w, join_axes(name_unit_ref, axis_v1_w)).\
            outerjoin(axis_v1_l, join_axes(name_unit_ref, axis_v1_l)).\
            outerjoin(axis_v2_w, join_axes(name_unit_ref, axis_v2_w)).\
            outerjoin(axis_v2_l, join_axes(name_unit_ref, axis_v2_l))

for row in q:
    print row
```

Comment: OK, perfect!, I still need to improve my SQL skills :-) I finally did it using pandas which I'm more comfortable with. Anyway, thank you for the SQL-way.

Answer (score 0):

This is the more "exotic" SQL for your question. I'm using SQL Server 2008+ to get the PIVOT command. I'm not sure if it's exactly covering the case for your columns though.

```
--Setup the table and data
create table #t
(
 name nvarchar(100) not null
,vector char(2) not null
,axis char(1) not null
,value int not null
,unit char(3) not null
,ref nvarchar(100) not null
);

insert into #t values ('name1','v1','W', 46504,'psi','ref1');
insert into #t values ('name1','v1','L', 51757,'psi','ref1');
insert into #t values ('name1','v2','W',   127,'psi','another ref');
insert into #t values ('name1','v2','L',   403,'psi','ref1');

-- Retrieve the data using SQL Server Pivot
-- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx
select * 
from 
(select 
  name
 ,vector + '-' + axis as vector_axis
 ,value
 ,unit
 ,ref
 from #t) as t
pivot (sum(value) for vector_axis IN
([v1-w]
,[v1-L]
,[v2-W]
,[v2-L]
)
) as p
```

[image]